# Can't Figure out how to display: none for the following class

Tags: html, css, wordpress, display

I'm a novice when it comes to HTML and CSS, I mostly use it to make custom changes to my websites so I apologize if this is a very basic question but I couldn't find the answer anywhere online thus far.

I'm trying to remove the "Total Reads" row from my author profiles but keep the "Total Posts" row.

This would be easy enough accept both the "Total Reads" and "Total Posts" both have a class name of "row" and both contain the same classes like "col total-label text-right" so I can't set one to display: none without affecting both. Does anyone know how I can bypass this, I've tried about a dozen different things and can't find anything online.

Here's a link to a sample author page on my site: https://www.thepostmillennial.com/members/barbrakay/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

you can use that it will just delete the first row

```
#buddypress .bbp-user-report .user-totals .row:first-of-type { display:none }
```

or you can do it inline style

```
<div class="row" style="display:none;">
```

Answer (score 0):

On the row you want to delete add this:

```
<div class="row" style="display:none;">
```

That will only affect that row in particular.

Answer (score 0):

try to add a hide class to your css like this

```
.hide {
  display:none;
}
```

and add this class to you HTML element that you want toi hide

```
<div class="row hide">...</div>
```

this appoach help you to hide other elements if you want

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to add any class in your HTML. then you can do something like this.

> Here .user-total is parent element of row

**For Hiding Total Reads:**

```
.user-totals row:first-child {
  display: none
}
```

or

```
.user-totals row:nth-child(1) {
  display: none
}
```

**For Hiding Total Posts:**

```
.user-totals row:last-child {
  display: none
}
```

or

```
.user-totals row:nth-child(2) {
  display: none
}
```